# Javascript in Drupal: this.nextElementSibling returns NULL in Drupal, but works in a plain HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, accordion

I have the following javascript method that tries to Toggle Collapse or Expand on a section of HTML:

```
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            window.alert(this);
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run the same exact HTML contents on a Static HTML file, the collapse, expand is working fine.   (Window.alert above shows [object HTMLButtonElement] in both Drupal and static HTML).  But when using the same identical HTML/JS/CSS code baked into my Drupal page, then this.nextElementSibling returns NULL, so toggle("show") can not be called.

Does anyone know why in Drupal that method woudl return NULL, but everything works fine in a static HTML file.

Here is the full content of the whole static HTML script (works fine):

```
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}
</style>

<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            window.alert(this);
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
The problem was due to Drupal injecting < p > tags around the < button > tags automatically.  I resorted to wrapping each < button > with a < div >, now Drupal leaves it alone, and doesnt add extra tags, so the next sibling logic is working fine. 
The final code:

```
    <!-- DRUPAL will wrap < button > tags with < p > tags if < button > tags are not enclosed with some sort of parent tag.  Therefore, divs around them are needed. -->
<div>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div>
<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `acc[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    target.classList.toggle("active");
    target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }`

Comment: Unfortunately same exact issue with the above code.  Works fine when used from static.html file, but when used in a Drupal Basic Page or Article (with Full HTML mode), target.nextElementSibling above returns NULL.

Comment: What version of Drupal? I suggest you take a look at the [Drupal Javascript API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview). Specifically the part about Drupal.behaviors

Comment: Drupal 7.34.    Thanks i'll read up more on the JS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inspected the HTML structure after the page finishes rendering, and found that Drupal is injecting < p > tags around my < button > tags.

The original HTML i provided was:

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

But here is what comes out of the HTML inspector:
[image]

(Note the < p > tags around the buttons ).   So it seems like I just have to modify my selection logic, to drill out past the < p > then back into the next neighbor div.   Kind of a hacky solution though.   I'd really prefer Drupal not to mess with the HTML I write...  Maybe there's an option to turn that type of formatting off.  Perhaps it's converting my newlines to < p > tags.  I'll also try writing the HTML in Drupal without using newlines to see if it helps.

Comment: So apparently, in order to be XHTML 1.0 Transitional, < button > tags must be enclosed in a parent element.   So Drupal is forcing me to be XHTML 1.0 Transitional by doing that for me with < p > tags....

Comment: your doctype will be dependent on the theme you have chosen to use.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the issue is happening because the code is running before the page itself as finished rendering.

You can set a breakpoint at that line (or use the `debugger` statement) and then examine the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Take care about the word **this** on JavaScript, the **this** will return data based on your scope, in order to don't lose the reference it is a common solution to store the **this** reference in a variable with the name self, like this:

```
var _self= this;
//then access later to the reference
_self.foo()
```

Try that solution,
Best